# Change of electric vector (and hence polarization) of photon after Compton scattering

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, polarization

I want to know how the electric vector (polarization) of individual photon changes after Compton scattering. Is that totally a random process, means the photon electric vector orientation change has uniform probability between $0$ to $2\pi$? I know that after Compton scattering the direction of Compton scattered photons have azimuthal asymmetry (probability high in perpendicular to linear polarization direction - if memory serves).

Comment: [“Polarization of Compton-scattered Gamma Rays”](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1277&context=honors_theses)